# How do I fix a slow running self-hosted website on a rpi3

Tags: wordpress, raspberry-pi, webserver, self-hosting

I'm hosting a website on a raspberry pi 3. I installed WordPress on it and got the DNS records set in cloudflare so that when the public IP changes, it updates the DNS records using the API.

It's running fine other than the fact that when I try and go to the website, it takes around 30-60 seconds to load the content of the default home page.

What are some steps that I can do to make it the website load quicker? I figure it's because I'm running it on an rpi3, and it might be overloading its RAM, but I feel like it should still at least be able to take less than a full minute to load.

I haven't tried a whole lot of anything yet to fix it because I don't really know where to start. This is my first time hosting a webserver and all of the information I can find is for a website hosted through a provider.